# Where do i extract strcasestr.3.gz to for gcc, gnu compiler on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, gcc

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, GNU Compiler on a desktop computer. I want to use strcasestr in c. But gcc does not find it. gcc gives me:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcasestr’;
```

I found: /usr/share/man/man3/strcasestr.3.gz. gcc is located at:

```
$ whereis gcc
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
```

I don't know where to extract it to so gcc will find it? Do I extract it to a temp folder and then copy it somewhere? Can someone please tell me how to extract strcasestr.3.gz to the right location so gcc finds it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935642/how-do-i-use-strcasestr

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. adding #define _GNU_SOURCE before all #includes took care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The link @steeldriver posted suggested adding `#define _GNU_SOURCE` above all #include declarations. This was the solution to using the strcasestr() function in a c program.